# Cpp class constructor explicit in the code

Tags: c++, class, explicit

```
0 class a{
1 public:
2   explicit a(int value=0)
3   : storedvalue{value}{}
4   int read() const
5   {return storedvalue;
6       }
7   private:
8   int storedvalue;

9 };
```

1)Can anyone explain what is this method called and difference between :storedvalue(value){} and :storedvalue{value}{} ,this part of code(**line 2 to 3**) and
2)also what is difference between const int read() and int read() const (**line 4**)?

Comment: please one question per question. `const int read()` returns a `const int`, `int read() const` is a `const` method that returns `int`

Comment: and perhaps find a better C++ book if yours does not explain these.